# Blogit is not routing in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, blogs

Hi guys,
I have just installed [blogit](https://github.com/KatanaCode/blogit) into my Rails 4 application. When I go to `/blog` I get routing error of every single route I have got. I get "undefined local variable or method". It is like that it won't load my routes at all.

Not sure if it make sense though. Please let me know what you want me to put here so you guys can have a look.

I have `current_user` defined in `ApplicationController`.
In the installation what I didn't understand is "declare which of your models acts as blogger in your app". That might be the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you specify `mount Blogit::Engine => "/blog"` in your routes.rb?

Comment: Yes indeed. I have followed the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is looking for this.

[Answer trail is in here. It is Explained fully](https://github.com/KatanaCode/blogit/issues/53)

So just to sum it up, I added main_app to all of the links in the view and all are good.
Basically when you are in the /blog you will be in the engine, and you need to tell the app the correct path. Thanks to [emaxon](https://github.com/emaxon).